# Condition of Homogenous Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We were be taught that a homogenous differential equation are those (for 1st order, 1st degree) that
$\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ should have same degree. Then we substitue y=vx and then reduce it to solve it by variable sepreable method

But in this question as i read in some text that he solved with homogenous method but the equation is not homogenous (or may be i am missing something). The equation is

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}+xsin(\frac{y}{x})$.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve a non linear equation given by $$y'=\frac{y}{x}+x\sin\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)$$
Let, $y=xv$, so we have that $$y'=xv'+v,$$then $$xv'+v=x\sin(v)+v \implies v'=\sin(v)$$Integrating both sides respect to $x$, we have that $$\int \csc(v)v'dx=\int dx \implies v=2\cot^{-1}(\exp(-x-c))$$
Therefore, $$y(x)=2x\cot^{-1}(c\exp(-x))$$

Comment: i know the solution but i asked something else?

Comment: This a first order $\color{red}{\text{nonlinear}}$ ODE.